# How to migrate SharePoint 2007 Data to Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, migration, office-365

I have SharePoint 2007 site on my server which have lists, libraries, custom web-parts, workflows etc. and i have another SharePoint Server on Office 365 which also have some lists,libraries and custom web-parts.

now i wants to transfer all data from SharePoint  server 2007 to office 365 how can i do this?
is there any tool for migration ?

Note : migration may not affect existing web-part and workflows of office 365

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Office 365 yet but one of the tools I've used previously the, SharePoint Migration utility, has recently been upgraded into the Metalogix Content Matrix, which does cater for a move to Office 365.  It will certainly move the content for you, but I've yet to check the literature for how it handles custom web parts.

http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx

Please note that I don't work for Metalogix.

Comment: what was the size of the data and how long did it take?

Comment: Native Database was about 40GB.  After auditing it, I managed to get it down to 25GB.  Via various queued jobs, this was sone in about 26 - 28 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this by copying the DB and then adding it to the newer one.

you can write your own PowerShell that can do this for you.
you can use 3rd part software like Metalogix, Sharegate, etc.

Comment: Are you sure? because, attaching db is not possible in SPO.